# Notice: Undefined index unsolve

Tags: php

Please Help me out., I don't know why this give's Undefined index when i run the file it gives undefined index and when i hit the submit button its successfully uploaded file. and notification removed.

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </form>

</body>
</html>

$name = $_FILES ['file'] ['name'];
$size = $_FILES ['file'] ['size'];
$type = $_FILES ['file'] ['type'];
$max_size = 2097152 ;
$extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.')+1));
$tmp_name = $_FILES ['file'] ['tmp_name'] ;
$location = 'uploads/' ;

if (isset($name)) { 
   if (!empty($name)) {
      if (($extension=='jpg'||$extension=='jpeg')&&$type=='image/jpeg'&&$size<=$max_size) {
         if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
     echo "Uploaded!";
     }

  } else { 
  echo "file must be jpg/jpeg and must be 2mb or less.";
  }

} else {
  echo "Please Upload a File.";
}
}
```

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Applications\File_Upload\upload.php on line 16

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Applications\File_Upload\upload.php on line 17

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Applications\File_Upload\upload.php on line 18

Notice: Undefined index: file in C:\xampp\htdocs\Applications\File_Upload\upload.php on line 21

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<body>

<form action="upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file"> <br><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit"> </form>

</body>
</html>
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $name = $_FILES ['file'] ['name'];
    $size = $_FILES ['file'] ['size'];
    $type = $_FILES ['file'] ['type']; $max_size = 2097152 ; echo $extension = strtolower(substr($name, strpos($name, '.')+1)); $tmp_name = $_FILES ['file'] ['tmp_name'] ; $location = 'uploads/' ;

    if (isset($name)) { 
        if (!empty($name)) {
            if (($extension=='jpg'||$extension=='jpeg')&&$type=='image/jpeg'&&$size<=$max_size) {
                if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location . $name)) {
                    echo "Uploaded!";
                }

            } else { 
                echo "file must be jpg/jpeg and must be 2mb or less.";
            }

        } else {
            echo "Please Upload a File.";
        }
    }
}   

?>
```